# Validate number sequence as quadkey (not just regex)

Tags: bing-maps, quadtree, azure-maps

I know quadkeys have the basic regex of [0-3]{6,23}.

But is it possible for a number to match that regex and not be a quadkey?
I.e. random number 2010210202020021

Given a random number, I would like to know if it is a quadkey or not and I'd like to know if there's a way to check beyond just a simple regex.

Seems like the best way may be to convert it to a long/lat and see if that's a valid location? Is it possible to convert it like that?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of quadkeys, that regex would always match valid quadkeys, however, if these quadkeys are valid in your map platform would depend on the platform.

- Bing Maps typically supports zoom levels 1 through 19 (additional zoom levels in select areas, usually via birdseye imagery which doesn't use quadkeys). Note that Bing Maps uses raster tiles that cover 256-pixel squares.
- In Azure Maps, many of the map tile services support zoom levels 0 to 22, and the map control itself can go down to zoom level 24 if you have custom map tiles. Note that Azure Maps uses both 256-pixel raster tiles, and vector tiles that cover 512-pixel squares.

For your regex, if you want to support all zoom levels you would need to adjust the numbers in the squiggly brackets.